# What is a good alternative to SQL Server for ASP.NET applications?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, rdbms

I've been looking into a lot of database's recently, and am not sure if it's because I'm bored or what, but I want to create a few web applications using database's other than MS SQL Server. Any suggestions that tie into ASP.NET nicely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd consider MySQL as the obvious alternative.

However, fundamentally one relational database is pretty much the same as another, more so when accessed through something like ADO.NET. If you're bored with SQL Server then rather than looking for an alternative why not look at trying different data access strategies?

You don't mention whether or not you're using an ORM (object relational mapper) which can make working with databases a lot more enjoyable than using standard ADO.NET, such as:

- NHibernate
- Entity Framework
- Linq to SQL
- Subsonic

IMO, sticking with SQL Server but trying out a few different ORM's would be much more interesting than switching to a different database altogether.

Or how about looking into using a document database, such as [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/)?

Comment: +1 for the second sentence. It makes no sense to try out something else out of boredom - at the end relational databases are relational databases. The devil is in the detail (and sql server is a good one - not hard to keep running), but on a higher level they are all pretty much the same.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend [VistaDB](http://www.vistadb.net/) and [MySql](http://www.mysql.com/?bydis_dis_index=1).

Comment: +1 I agree. Both have .net providers so all the code you are used to writing with sql will be the same except specific for these databases.

Comment: true. both have reliable .net providers. only difference is vistaDB is commercial  but its worth the cost.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at [Connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/). Most databases there have a .NET provider available.

Answer (score 1):

Define "good".

Do you want to have a database as a simple data store, or should the database also implement business logic (stored procedures, triggers)?

Do you want to ship your apps and therefore require easy of installation?

Does it matter if the database is commercial, when MSSQL offers a free version?

As @richeym pointed out: are SQL statement a sufficient interface, or do you require an ORM?